# Whats the best way to write python code into a python file?

Tags: python

I want to write a script (generate_script.py) generating another python script (filegenerated.py)

So far i have created generate_script.py:

```
import os
filepath = os.getcwd()
def MakeFile(file_name):
    temp_path = filepath + file_name
    file = open(file_name, 'w')
    file.write('def print_success():')
    file.write('    print "sucesss"')
    file.close()
    print 'Execution completed.'
```

The file (filegenerated.py) looks now like this:

> def print_success():    print "sucesss"

Now i don't want to manually insert all linebreaks (also due to operating system difficulties)...is there a template system i can use writing python code into a python file? Does someone have an example?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which template systems did you find that can't generate python code?

Comment: Try mako templates: http://www.makotemplates.org/

Comment: Python handles newlines in a universal manner; writing newlines in text mode will write the correct line endings for your platform.

Comment: "i don't want to manually insert all spaces" - indentation is significant, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do :/

Comment: @KarolyHorvath i meant newlines...spaces are not that difficult ;-P I edited the question...thanks

Comment: @Jurudocs: solved the indentation "problem" ;) see my update

Comment: @KarolyHorvath thanx! AT ALL: nice surprise that this question is getting upvoted ;-P Thanks all!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could just use a multiline string:

```
import os
filepath = os.getcwd()
def MakeFile(file_name):
    temp_path = filepath + file_name
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        f.write('''\
def print_success():
    print "sucesss"        
''')
    print 'Execution completed.'
```

If you like your template code to be indented along with the rest of your code, but dedented when written to a separate file, you could use `textwrap.dedent`:

```
import os
import textwrap

filepath = os.getcwd()
def MakeFile(file_name):
    temp_path = filepath + file_name
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        f.write(textwrap.dedent('''\
            def print_success():
                print "sucesss"        
                '''))
    print 'Execution completed.'
```

Comment: okay putting that into a big string is for me now pretty convinient! Thanks

Answer (score 13):

```
lines = []
lines.append('def print_success():')
lines.append('    print "sucesss"')
"\n".join(lines)
```

If you're building something complex dynamically:

```
class CodeBlock():
    def __init__(self, head, block):
        self.head = head
        self.block = block
    def __str__(self, indent=""):
        result = indent + self.head + ":\n"
        indent += "    "
        for block in self.block:
            if isinstance(block, CodeBlock):
                result += block.__str__(indent)
            else:
                result += indent + block + "\n"
        return result
```

You could add some extra methods, to add new lines to the block and all that stuff, but I think you get the idea..

Example:

```
ifblock = CodeBlock('if x>0', ['print x', 'print "Finished."'])
block = CodeBlock('def print_success(x)', [ifblock, 'print "Def finished"'])
print block
```

Output:

```
def print_success(x):
    if x>0:
        print x
        print "Finished."
    print "Def finished."
```

Comment: nice edit! Thats definetly the solution for more complex code...!

Answer (score 5):

Try using \n and \t

```
import os
filepath = os.getcwd()
def MakeFile(file_name):
    temp_path = filepath + file_name
    file = open(file_name, 'w')
    file.write('def print_success():\n')
    file.write('\tprint "sucesss"')
    file.close()
    print 'Execution completed.'
```

to output

```
def print_success(): 
    print "sucesss"
```

or multiline

```
import os
filepath = os.getcwd()
def MakeFile(file_name):
    temp_path = filepath + file_name
    file = open(file_name, 'w')
    file.write('''
def print_success():
    print "sucesss"
    ''')
    file.close()
    print 'Execution completed.'
```

Comment: It is good to point out that `\t` gives a tab character, but PEP8 says that four spaces is the preferred standard for indentation.

Answer (score 2):

untubu answer is probably the more pythonic answer, but in your code example you're missing new line chars and tabs.

```
file.write("def print_success():\n")
file.write('\tprint "success"\n\n')
```

This will give you the spacing and newlines.  The link below will give you some tips on the accepted ones.

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use jinja to construct blocks, and change needed code