# Programmatically indenting Python code in a self-rewriting script?

Tags: python

I'm trying to have some fun so I decided to see what I can do in terms of creating self-rewriting scripts. I made this:

```
import os
import string

f = open('rewrite.py', 'r+')
text = f.read()
text = str(f.write("while True:" + text))
f.seek(0)
f.write(text)
f.close()

os.system("python rewrite.py")
```

But it sort of makes a mess since it doesn't indent anything after the while loop is inserted. The file itself is also called **rewrite.py**. I know this will be an infinite loop and create a huge file but I wanted to see if it was possible.

**Edit:**
After running this script, the file contents now look like this:

```
Nonert os
import string

f = open('rewrite.py', 'r+')
text = f.read()
text = str(f.write("while True:" + text))
f.seek(0)
f.write(text)
f.close()

os.system("python rewrite.py")
while True:import os
import string

f = open('rewrite.py', 'r+')
text = f.read()
text = str(f.write("while True:" + text))
f.seek(0)
f.write(text)
f.close()

os.system("python rewrite.py")
```

Comment: `f.write` returns an integer - this code does not do what you think it does.

Comment: What about iterate and add `"    "` (4 spaces) before every line?

Comment: Sorry, @nneonneo fixed.

Comment: If you want indentation why don't you add it? Not sure what your question really is, only you know what is in the file and the indentation is up to you to add

Comment: No, that *really* doesn't do what you expect - at this point you're just writing the file-length to the start of the file. That won't yield a meaningful script. You say "it sort of makes a mess" - did you test the code?

Comment: `f.write("\n"+text + "\nwhile True:\n\tpass")` forget all the rest bar open and close and read, you might want to do a `f.seek(0);f.truncate()` before writing and be ready to kill the script

Answer (score 3):

[Whats the best way to write python code into a python file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815503/whats-the-best-way-to-write-python-code-into-a-python-file)

The second answer on this is really well done.  I would recommend using the class that he made!

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following is in the spirit of what you're trying to do.  Note I got rid of the `while True:` as it keeps your program from rerunning itself a second time -- it gets stuck in the infinite loop and never calls `os.system()` again.  Read the three `if` clauses carefully before adding anything thing else to this script.  Run at your own risk:

```
import os

text = ''
f = open('rewrite.py', 'r+')
for line in f:
    if line.startswith("import") or line.startswith("os.system"):
        text += line
    elif line == "\n":
        text += line
        text += "for i in range(3):\n"
    else:
        text += ' ' * 4 + line
f.seek(0)
f.write(text)
f.close()
os.system("python rewrite.py")
```

If all goes well, it should eventually stop with the error:

```
SystemError: too many statically nested blocks
```

Answer (score 0):

Just invented this code for my own purposes.  If you were to generate a python function by writing a code string to a module, you'd want to match the indentation, so tabification becomes important:

```
   def tabify_code(self, code:str):
      lines = code.splitlines()
      
      if len(lines) <= 1:
         return code
         
      tab_size = self.num_indent_spaces
      orig_tab_size = 0
      k = 0
      
      for line in lines:
         if line.strip():
            spaces = 0
            for c in line:
               if c == ' ':
                  spaces += 1
               else:
                  lines[k] = (spaces, line)
                  orig_tab_size = math.gcd(spaces, orig_tab_size)
                  break
         k += 1
      
      tabified = []
      
      for (spaces, line) in lines:   
         if original_tab_size != 0:
            tabs = int(spaces / orig_tab_size)
         else:
            tabs = 0
         line = line.strip(' ')
         line = f'{" " * tab_size * tabs}{line}'
         tabified.append(line)
         
      return "\n".join(tabified)
```

It uses GCD to determine the given tab size of the code passed in.  That's so that we can easily count how many tabs are needed.  Clearly GCD is appropriate and will indeed work for Python code.